# Unable to access table fields using range variable in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ to SQL in my project.
I have two tables Category and Artifacts with a one-to-many relationship between Category and Artifacts. On the basis of CatgID I am trying to delete artifacts. The query that I have written checks whether any artifact exist with a foreign key of id, then I am grouping Artifact ID to g so as to count so that I can make a condition to pass the Artifact ID as parameter to a function which will delete everything in the Artifacts table.

I am not able to select ArtId using the same range variable 'a'. Why not? How can I do this or otherwise achieve what I want?

```
public static void DeleteCategory(int id)
{
    var result = from a in adb.Artifacts
                     where a.CatgId == id
                     group a by a.ArtId into g
                     select new { count = g.Count(), **artid = a.ArtId** }; //not able to get ArtId using range variable a.

    if (result.count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var r in result)
        {
            MyArtifact.DeleteByKey(r.artid);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use g.ArtId because you group by ArtId:

```
public static void DeleteCategory(int id)
{
    var result = from a in adb.Artifacts
                 where a.CatgId == id
                 group a by a.ArtId into g
                 select new { count = g.Count(), artid = g.Key }; //not able to get ArtId using range variable a.

    if (result.count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var r in result)
        {
            MyArtifact.DeleteByKey(r.artid);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey hcb,
I have tried using range variable g and to access ArtId of Artifact table. But when I do that, I face this error 

"'System.Linq.IGrouping<int,AdlibCoreModel.Artifact>' does not contain a definition for 'ArtId' and no extension method 'ArtId' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<int,AdlibCoreModel.Artifact>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: You can use g.First().ArtId. I think that should work (i'll also edit the answer)

Comment: yeah this works but I am not able to understand the concept of using First(). It says First() returns the first element of a sequence!!

Comment: Allright. I found the real solution btw. You can use g.Key, it represents the key you use to group, so g.Key == a.ArtId.

Comment: g is a group of a's grouped by ArtId. First() is the first artefact of that group.